# Groovysh failing to start with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, ubuntu, groovy, crash

I am runnig into an error when trying to start the groovy-shell on ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS):

Version is

```
falk@falkpc:~$ groovysh -version
@|green Groovy Shell|@ 2.4.15
```

But calling groovysh fails:

```
falk@falkpc:~$ groovysh 
Gtk-Message: 18:37:05.964: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
FATAL: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:104)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.setInput(ConsoleReader.java:330)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:248)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:236)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:228)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.PatchedConsoleReader.<init>(PatchedConsoleReader.groovy:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.<init>(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.run(Groovysh.groovy:588)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh$run$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.run(Groovysh.groovy:574)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.startGroovysh(Main.groovy:184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.groovy:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:138)
```

I was using this installation successfully for a while. I have no clue which change causes this behaviour.

Any ideas anyone?

Edit: the line "Gtk-Message: ..." no longer appers after installing

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

However this does not yet fix the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `groovysh` using Java 9 (see https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server/issues/752)

If you don't mind upgrading to the latest version then do:

```sh
# install Java 11 OpenJDK
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk

# update JAVA_HOME (you can get dir via: update-java-alternatives -l)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

groovysh
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly missing library/dependency: `canberra-gtk-module`.

Try installing the same and later test groovysh:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

**Edited:**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)

Possibly, you are using different version/bundle of JDK/JRE to compile and run.

Comment: Thank you. That did indeed fix the warning message (the line "Gtk-Message..."). However, the following error still appers.

Comment: "Possibly, you are using different version/bundle to compile and run."

I am not sure what you mean: I am really only trying to run groovysh. There is not a source-file that I would compile and then run the compiled file. Instead I only run the command `> groovysh`